# Unreferenced library and ambiguous DLLs when porting Skinned Model sample to MonoGame

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I'm trying to port the Skinned Model animation sample from XNA to Monogame and I got several dll errors.

To get the SkinnedModelProcessor.cs class to work properly I had to reference the content pipeline dlls and this gives the following errors:

```
error CS0012: The type 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Matrix' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=842cf8be1de50553'.
```

And a bunch of other errors related to the Matrix struct. Matrix gets recognized and Intellisensed, but still wants the other Matrix class. (It picks up the correct Matrix class when `using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.Processors;` is removed but then the ModelContent type doesn't get referenced.

If I add the assembly as the error tells me I get tons of errors about duplicate data types (the MonoGame and XNA ones crashing each other because they have the same name and namespace.).

I've found solutions online that edit the .sln file and exclude the XNA assemblies out of the build event, but they don't seem to do anything. You can view the sample on MSDN, nothing was changed to the code and most classes aside from the SkinnedModelProcessor compile correctly. Any help?

Thanks,

Nick.

Answer (score 0):

The Monogame doesn't use XNA assemblies after project being built. Skinned model processor is a XNA assembly namely extension of a XNA Content Pipeline. When you are trying to run your project already ported game is trying to access XNA assemblies which cannot be supported by monogame project.

P.S. As you could noticed the monogame project doesn't use XNA content project. It has the assets folder where you put your precompiled .xnb content. Therefore there is no XNA content assemblies which are referenced to a project.